# Emberjs Rendering a template using {{action ??? on="focusIn"}}

Tags: javascript, templates, ember.js, rendering, action

I want to render 'we-is-app-complete.hbs' inside of a sidebar .hbs file, named 'workflow_editor_sidebar.hbs', when the user clicks and targets a header in the main content of that page ('workflow_editor.hbs'), but I do not wish to alter the current route.

I tried {{ action on="focusIn }} but I don't have a function defined in the workflow_editor_controller.js to put in between 'action' and 'on='. Let's call this undefined function 'renderIsAppCompleteTemplate:'

If a different header is selected, the sidebar will hide 'we-is-app-complete.hbs' and render a new template, but for this example we'll focus on only 'we-is-app-complete.hbs'

in 'we-is-app-complete.hbs'

```
<h2> This is the code that I want to render.</h2>
```

in 'workflow_editor_sidebar.hbs'

```
{{#if 'renderIsAppCompleteTemplate}
  {{render 'we-is-app-complete.hbs}}
{{/if}}
```

in 'workflow_editor.hbs' == '/workflow_editor/new'

```
<div {{ action 'renderIsAppCompleteTemplate' on="focusIn" }} class="fees-container collapsible">
  <div class="arrow-nav collapsibleHeader fees-edit-selection">
    <h2>Permit Fees 
      <h4 class="inline-block"> ((#)) of Calculations</h4>
    </h2>
    <img src="images/menu.png" class="menu-icon" id="m1">
  </div>
</div>
```

in 'workflow_editor_controller.js'

```
VpcYeoman.WorkflowEditorController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  renderisAppCompleteTemplate: function() {
   */ nothing yet */
})
```

Feel free to suggest alternate or more efficient methods of solving this problem.

EDIT: I've done something similar by rendering a sidebar template based on the current. Here's the code if it sparks any inspiration.

For the controller

```
  showRecordBasedOnRoute: function(){
    var curPath =this.get('currentPath');
    if(curPath == 'application'){
      return false;  
    } else if (curPath == 'record'){
     return true; 
    } //other things
  }.property('currentPath'),
```

&&

```
      {{#if showRecordBasedOnRoute}}
        {{render 'record-sidebar'}}
      {{/if}}
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately you can only have one active route at the time. I had the same problem. There's an experimental version that let's you use a sub-router with an independent route, but it's not worth the trouble.

What you're currently doing works fine. However, you need to define the action inside an actions object.

```
VpcYeoman.WorkflowEditorController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  actions: {
    renderisAppCompleteTemplate: function() {
      */ nothing yet */
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: Thank you, but defining the action is what I'm having trouble with. I don't wish to change the route and {{render}} hasn't done that so far in my use of it. I want to use on="focusIn" to create a focus on the header that's activ, so defining an action in the controller seems a little inane since I've already made an {{if}} statement to use {{render 'template.hbs' and declared that the header must be focusIn for that {{if}} statement to be true. I've used a similar method to conditionally render templates based on the current path, which i'll update in the question.

Comment: Either way works. You either change the route or a controller prop.